# Is it possible to use TemplaVoilà and Backend Layout on the same installation?

Tags: typo3, templavoila

I have a TYPO3 4.7 environment which holds 3 websites.
All theses website use TemplaVoilà template engine.

We are now redesigning one of these site and I wonder if I can use Fluid and Backend Layout instead of TemplaVoilà.

[image]

It seems that I have to desactivate TemplaVoilà in the extension manager to be able to use be layout.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Dislaimer: I'm not using TemplaVoilà myself.*

The TCA Overrides of EXT:templavoila replace the backend layout fields with the respecting fields of TemplaVoilà, see [here](https://git.typo3.org/TYPO3CMS/Extensions/templavoila.git/blob/HEAD:/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/pages.php).

By reading this code, it should be possible to have both the TemplaVoilà fields and the Backend Layout fields if

- "Enable data structure selection" is inactive and
- "Enable the classic Page module" is active

in the extension configuration in the Extension Manager.

Comment: Thanks for that. This gave me the possibility to enable the Fluid BE-Layout for one Tree. But in the Backend it sill shows the TV-View - not my Fluid Layout. Do you have for any chance a idea why?